# JSP (MVC DAO): return after action to the same page

Tags: jsp, model-view-controller, dao

I need to return to the same page after specific actions, such as login / logout / switch language etc. All my navigation is proceed due DAO MVC: request go to Controller and Controller launch appropriate action. Almost all actions requires many input request parameters.

My **Question**: if I need actions that return me to the same page than I need to save all page-needed-params in hidden fields in page.jsp?

*I mean, is it right to save all parameters/attributes (that are needed to generate page.jsp) in hidden fields of page.jsp?

Comment: "f I need actions that return me to the same page than I need to save all page-needed-params in hidden fields in page.jsp?" confusing

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question clearly. You can use session to store your parameters/attributes so you can use them in every pages (in the same session).

Comment: no, i want save not only parameters but also attributes (large ArrayLists of Objects). So I can't put it into session. Any other idea?

Comment: Please explain your question clearly ...You can save any object into session, what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that I can't save large objects in session (it is bad practice)